# Angular 6 how to show spinner on menu item or hyperlink click

Tags: angular

I would like to show a processing spinner in my Angular 6 app sidenav and home component as soon as a menu item, a route link or a hyperlink is clicked.  Here are the HomeComponent and SideNav.  I also have a spinner in the datasource component and it is working when the app makes connection to the webapi service. I copied the code to the SideNav and Home, but it is not displayed.  Thanks for your help.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private spinnerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean> (false);
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.spinnerSubject.asObservable();
  spinnerColor = 'warn';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    
      activatedRoute.url.subscribe((s: UrlSegment[]) => {

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  appCardClicked(routePath: string) {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(true);
    this.router.navigate([routePath], {
      replaceUrl: true
    });
    // this.spinnerSubject.next(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-container">
  <mat-spinner [color]="spinnerColor" *ngIf="loading$ | async"></mat-spinner>
</div>

<mat-card class="app-card" (click)="appCardClicked('/lccp')">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      A summary goes here.
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

```js
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'vertical-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
  private spinnerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); 
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.spinnerSubject.asObservable();

  routerLinkClicked(): void {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(true);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'" [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="menuIsOpened || (isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar class="darkNavy">
      <img src="assets/logo.gif" routerLink="/home" style="padding-top:40px" alt="logo" />
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list style="padding-top:50px">
      <a *ngFor="let item of verticleMenu" mat-list-item routerLink="{{item.RouteLink}}" (click)="routerLinkClicked()">
        {{item.Title}}
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar class="darkNavy">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <div class='menu' style="display:flex; align-items: flex-end">
          <i class="material-icons" aria-label="Side nav toggle icon" (click)="toggleMenu()" matTooltip="menu">menu

          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </i>
          <span *ngFor="let item of horizontalMenu" mat-list-item routerLink="{{item.RouteLink}}">&nbsp;
            {{item.Title}}
          </span>
        </div>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <ng-content>
      <!-- routed content is projected here -->
    </ng-content>
    <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="loading$ | async" role="presentation">
      <mat-spinner [color]="spinnerColor"></mat-spinner>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: This should work. [Sample Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qctgyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. It's identical to what I have.  It doesn't work on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a DIV after the ng-content in the nav.component.htm. The spinner in the Nav component is showing up. I also did router.events.subscribe() and exam the event type to toggled on and off the spinner.  However, the spinner in the Home component never show up.